# Add a constraint with a where statement

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a `NOT NULL` to a column that is conditional on another column.

```
ALTER TABLE mailers ALTER COLUMN original_id SET NOT NULL
```

WHERE offer_type = 'client cross'

In other words, if one column have `'client cross'` do not let a different column be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `NOT NULL` column constraint with a condition. Either the column can contain `NULL` values or it can't.

However, you can create a normal [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) for the entire row:

```
ALTER TABLE mailers
ADD CONSTRAINT "non-null_original_id_for_client-cross"
    CHECK (original_id IS NOT NULL OR offer_type <> 'client cross');
```